# Is Koro-sensei fireproof?

Tags: assassination-classroom

Koro sensei is super cool and ultra powerful. Although he has many weakness like water, special knives and bombs. I want to know if he is also fireproof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far there has not been any sign of a fiery attack or his ability to resist it, besides the hot weather. Which seems to cause him a quite extreme fatigue. He also is said to handle hot food pretty badly.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't that mean he can be killed if set on fire? 10 billion yen yeah!!!

Comment: @Dipu Probably means he would be slowed down quite a bit, but I think that even if he were still to move at mach1 the flames would extinguish through his cheer speed.

Comment: I don't know why the author had not mentioned anything about fire. It is the most basic element!

Comment: what about they trap him in a really, really hot room? would he melt? also, they haven't tried electricity yet have they?

Comment: @eha1234 Electricity could be a valid new question :). Discussing about locking him up in a hot room or other similar things should probably be done in the chat instead of the comments ^^

Comment: Another point supporting this is when the space shuttle is reentering the atmosphere, he tries to influence its trajectory by punching it a bit, but he can barely touch it because it is too hot for him.